# Javascript Multiplication Timetable

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a Javascript Multiplication Timetable for any number entered in the input box. So that when I click the button "Generate" it would produce a multiplication of numbers from 1 to 12 and then print out its result in HTML.
The Output result would then be printed in HTML Table. So far I have created the following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC>

<html>
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>5 Multiplication Table</title>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="timetable.js"></script> -->
</head>
<body>
   <script>
      function timesTable(){
      for (var i = 0; i <= 12; i++){
          var number1 ={}; //Empty placeholder for input
          var number1 = +document.getElementById("number1").value;
          var input = number1 * i;
          var generate = +document.getElementById("answers").value = input;   
          }
        }
   </script>
   <table>
     <tr>
        <td>Time Table for:</td>
        <td>
           <input type="text" id = "num1" /></td>
        <td rowspan="2">
           <input type="button" value="Generate" onclick="timesTable()"/>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:right" id="answers">Time Table:</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Earlier I had it working, however without the user entering a number. The code is below:<html>
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>5 Multiplication Table</title>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="timetable.js"></script> -->

</head>
<body>
<script>

 var fiveTimesTable = [
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12

]
for (var i=0;i<fiveTimesTable.length;i++)
{

document.write(fiveTimesTable[i] * 5 + "<br>");


}

</script>

</body>
</html>

Comment: Please use something like [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com) when referencing code in comments.

Comment: Also you haven't actually said what the problem is. Are you getting any errors? Is the output not what you expect?

Comment: My code doesnt display any output of a number i entered in in the input box when I click generate button

Comment: You'll want to use the Error console in Chrome or similar feature in another browser to debug this.  That way you can see the errors being thrown when you push the button.  Straight away, when I dropped this in JSFiddle and pulled up the Chrome console ( right click, inspect element, console tab) I noticed the first error - 'num1' vs 'number1'.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you're going to have to parse the users's input as a value - `parseFloat` or `parseInt` will work for that, depending on whether you want a floating point or integer value .

Secondly, you'll probably want a new table row for each multiplier and product: for example,

```
<tr><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>42</td></tr>
<tr><td>2></td><td>84</td></tr>
```

etc.  The tricky thing here is being able to add these to the end of the table on user input, and then remove them again when the button is next pressed. Though I like keeping things basic myself, I would definitely encourage you to use JQuery to do the html updating of the table - otherwise, finding each of the rows you added is just painful.  You can use something like

```
$(".timestable").remove()
```

to remove all/any previous timestable rows (http://api.jquery.com/remove/), and then code such as

```
$('#mytable').append("<tr class='timestable'>...</tr>")
```

to write out each row of the new (or first) times table (http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: I need a Javascript version - a more pragammatic approach than declarative using Jquery

Comment: how is JQuery not programmatic?  How is JQuery different than any other javascript approach, when it comes down to it?  JQuery _is_ javascript, just a convenient library.  You can do the same thing with native functions createElement() and appendChild() but, aside from being very inconvenient, that opens the door to all sorts of cross-browser issues.  Trust me, as an ex-anti-jquerier, you want jquery for this.